# How to get feature fields and values?

Tags: arcobjects, feature-class, fields-attributes

How can I get features from EID? I cannot define a Geodatabase connection since it changes. I have to get it from `IUtilityNetworkAnalysisExt` or IEditor. I figured out how to get EIDs on downstream. I would like to get fields and values by EIDs.

Comment: What is EID? What is the software? Please [edit] the new info into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have used the `ITraceSolverGEN.FindPath` method and have an enumerator of type `IEnumNetEIDs`?

I have not tried this but it looks like you can pass this into an `IEIDHelper` object to create another enumerator called an `IEnumEIDInfo` which you can pass through the `IEnumNetEID` object and get an `IEIDInfo` object which will will return an `IFeature` object.